# Magento: Sorting wishlist product collection by price and updated date

Tags: php, magento

I want to sort the wishlist product collection by product's date and price.
Can anyone help me out please...
Here is my code

```
public function getWishlistCollection(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer = null){
        if($customer):
            $wishlists = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
            if($wishlists->getItemCollection()->getSize()):
                $wishlists = $this->favorites->getItemCollection();
                $wishlists->addWishListSortOrder('added_at', 'DESC');
                $wishlists->getSelect()->limit(10, 0);
                return $wishlists;
            endif;
            return;
        endif;
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No the item collection is not the product collection.  In this case you need to create the product collection from your wishlist item collection.

Use the code below:

```
$wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
    $arrProductIds = array();
    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
        $arrProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
    }
}
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $arrProductIds))
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'ASC');

foreach($productsCollection as $product)
{
    echo $product->getprice();
    echo $product->getCreatedAt();
}
```